# getting items from context menu in binding listview WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, visual-studio-2012, contextmenu

I'am new in Microsoft visual studio WPF C# ..
I write code that show a context menu for binding listview and when we right click to the item in list it will remove it ...
I want to get the value of the item before we remove it

**the xaml

```
<ListView Name="listview1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="350" Margin="251,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="214" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Remove"
                Click="MenuItemDelete_Click" 
        Command="{Binding RemoveItem}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}" />
            </ContextMenu>

        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>

                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Dtime" DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=Dtime}" 
                  Header=" Date" Width="120"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Patient"  DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=Patient}"   
                  Header="Patient" Width="80"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

**the code

```
 class myresult {

        public String Dtime{ get; set; }
        public String Patient{ get; set; }

    }




 private void MenuItemDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (listview1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                return;
            }

// here I will get the Item I want but I cant get the value inside the item                 

       var asw = listview1.Items.GetItemAt(listview1.SelectedIndex);



        listview1.Items.RemoveAt(listview1.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `DataContext` of the `SelectedItem` and cast it to a `myresult` object.

```
myresult result = ((FrameworkElement)listview1.SelectedItem).DataContext as myresult;
```

Alternatively, you can use the same `SelectedIndex` method you were using previously.

```
myresult result = ((FrameworkElement)asw).DataContext as myresult;
```

Comment: i get an error (invalid cast exception ) (Unable to cast object of type myresult to type (system.windows.FrameworkElement)

Comment: From my examples, which method are you using? It looks like you don't even need to cast to `FrameworkElement` at all. If you're using the second method, which I'm guessing you are, try this: `myresult result = asw as myresult;`.